# how to implement paypal suspend subscription on reactjs

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

Hi i've been using paypal's sample code but adapted with react-paypal-js.

I'm wondering if there is an example for suspend subscription?

There doesn't seem to be an equivalent suspendSubscription? I tried looking at subscription API but not sure how to adapt that here. Thanks!

```
 <PayPalButtons
              createSubscription={(data, actions) => {
                return actions.subscription
                  .create({
                    /* Creates the subscription */
                    plan_id: 'P-xx',
                    quantity: subscriptionCount, // The quantity of the product for a subscription
                  })
                  .then((orderId) => {
                    // Your code here after create the order
                    console.log("order id created ", orderId)
                    return orderId;
                  });
              }}
              
              onApprove={(data, actions) => {
                console.log('approved data! ', data);
              }}
            />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suspending a subscription is done with server API calls, so reactjs is not relevant.

See the [Subscriptions documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/customize/pause-resume/), which gives an example in curl format

```sh
curl -v -X POST https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-BW452GLLEP1G/suspend
-H "Content-Type: application/json" 
-H "Authorization: Bearer <Access-Token>" 
-d '{
  "reason": "Customer-requested pause"
}'
```

(There is no SDK for Subscriptions API operations; use direct HTTPS API calls with an [oauth2 access token](https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/#link-getanaccesstoken))

Comment: Hi actually i just saw this https://developer.paypal.com/sdk/js/reference/ and I'm trying the actions.subscription.revise way. But passing id and quantity = 0 gets me a Error: Expected subscription payload to be passed. 

Otherwise it seems i have to do a fetch call using that path i suppose

Comment: you are right, while revise is a function it seems suspend is not..

Comment: Correct; revising a subscription (actions.subscription.revise) is a separate topic from suspending a subscription. Moreover, the suspend API is *not* to be called from a client-side fetch. The API is to be used from a server.